# Two slugs in one URL pattern

Tags: python, regex, django

How can I put two slugs in one url pattern? I have a model Link with a many to one relationship with a model category.

```
url(
    regex=r'^(?P<category_slug>[\w-]+)/(?P<pk>\d+)(?:/(?P<slug>[\w\d-]+))?/$',
    view=views.LinkDetailView.as_view(),
    name='link_detail'
),
```

Right now two slugs is working. But is accepting whatever you write in the category_slug section of the url.

Let's say: You write 127.0.0.1:8000/there_is_no_name_like_that_in_the_database/pk/slug this. You are going to this page but there is no category with this name. I don't know why it's doing this.

## links/views.py

```
class LinkDetailView(FormMixin, DetailView):
    model = Link
    context_object_name = 'link'
    form_class = CommentForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(LinkDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Link)
        obj_id = self.kwargs['pk']
        context['comments'] = Comment.objects.filter(content_type=content_type, object_id = obj_id)
        context['comment_form'] = CommentForm(initial={
                                                    'content_type': self.object.get_content_type,
                                                    'object_id': self.object.id
                                                    })
        category = Link._meta.get_field('category').rel.to
        context['uni_kabile'] = category.objects.all()
        return context

        ...
```

Comment: The only keyword argument you actually use seems to be 'pk', so as long as that exists you see a page, the values of the slugs are never used.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich , Yes right. I've just realize. How can I fix this?

Comment: By using them in the database query? Look at the `DetailView` class and its ascendants, their working is straightforward. — **edit**: it is also well described in the [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#django.views.generic.detail.DetailView); you want to override the `get_object` method.

Comment: @spectras , Thank you. :)

Comment: @RemcoGerlich you should make that as answer so that it can be accepted.

Comment: @spectras , When I do this    
`def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return get_object_or_404(Link, pk=self.kwargs['pk'], slug=self.kwargs['slug'])`

Link slug is working but category_slug doesn't. How can I implement category slug via get_object() ?